# Asp.net application configuration for BASIC Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, basic-authentication

I have written an asp.net application that only hosts a series of web services (.asmx) .
I would like to be able to use a custom basic authentication mechanism to authenticate requests.

I have found [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication) that describes how to do that :

I have written a `HttpModule` as It said and I have added it in my web.Config. No authentication scheme is set in web.config (no authentication tag) and also there's no authorization tag in web.config.

The problem is this module never hit no matter if I enable basic authentication in IIS or disable it (and enable anonymous access).

The question is what am I doing wrong or missing ?

UPDATE :

config file :

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="BasicAuthHttpModule" type="WebServiceWrapper.BasicAuthHttpModule, WebServiceWrapper"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Have you added the module to your web.config? Can you post the relevant sections from your config?

Comment: @SimonHalsey Yes I have added the module.I updated the question

Comment: You need to add it under the system.webServer section if you're running in integrated mode (which you probably are)